# SQL Distinct Pair Groupings

Tags: sql

I am interested in manipulating my data like so:

My Source Data:

```
From | To | Rate
----------------
EUR  | AUD | 1.5895
EUR  | BGN | 1.9558
EUR  | GBP | 0.7347
EUR  | USD | 1.1151
GBP  | AUD | 2.1633
GBP  | BGN | 2.6618
GBP  | EUR | 1.3610
GBP  | USD | 1.5176
USD  | AUD | 1.4254
USD  | BGN | 1.7539
USD  | EUR | 0.8967
USD  | GBP | 0.6589
```

In regards to "distinct pairs", I consider the following to be "duplicates".

```
EUR | USD matches USD | EUR
EUR | GBP matches GBP | EUR
GBP | USD matches USD | GBP
```

I want my source data to be filtered such that it removes any 1 of the above "duplicates", such that my final table is 3 records less than the original. I do not care which record from the "duplicates" is kept or removed, just so long as only 1 is selected.

I have tried many variations of Joins, Exists, Except, Distinct, Group By, logical comparisons (< >) and I feel like I am so close with any given approach... but it just does not seem to click.

My favorite effort has involved inner joining on EXCEPT:

```
SELECT a.[FROM], a.[TO], a.[Rate]
FROM Table a
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT DISTINCT [From], [To]
  FROM Table 
  EXCEPT
  (
    SELECT [TO] as [From], [From] as [To]
    FROM Table 
  )
) b
ON a.[From] = b.[From] AND a.[To] = b.[To]
```

But alas, it removes all of the matched pairs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can suggest something very easy, if it doesn't matter which one of then you want, than you can pick only the one that his rate is bigger than 1 or on the contrary the one smaller. Each pare should be 1 rate bigger and one smaller (make sense) so

```
Select * from table where rate>1
```

Comment: very good observation, you can may be use `>=1` to handle the case where both are equal.

Comment: Thanks. It's not very likely for something like this to happen especially in this case.. and also the result would be that you will have duplicated when its equal.

Comment: A great observation regarding how currency rates work. I have been able to apply this fundamental with great success, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One way to remove the duplicates that doesn't depend on the rates:

```
select s.*
from source s
where from < to
union all
select s.*
from source s
where to > from and
      not exists (select 1 from source s2 where s.from = s2.to and s.to = s2.from);
```

Note: I did not put escape characters around `from` and `to`, although you would need them in your actual query.

Answer (score 1):

Just to make it complete an `DISTINCT ON` solution:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(Least(from, to), Greatest(from, to)) *
FROM
source AS s1
ORDER BY Least(from, to), Greatest(from, to)
```